# How to differentiate each variable in a class by the copy constructor

Tags: c++, compilation

Think I have a class

```
class Man{
public:
int age;
int height;
}
```

Then in main

```
 Man black_man;
 black_man.age=20;
 black_man.height = 180;

 Man white_man = black_man;
```

So here the copy constructor how to differentiate `age` from `height`and copy exactly correctly. When compiling does compiler assign any index or prefix to each variable to identify uniquely something like `name mangling` for functions? simply what is the mechanism behind this?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  By default, the copy constructor will copy each member of the same name.

Comment: An implementation has to perform a member-wise copy. *How* it does that is not specified by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of C++, when relying upon default constructors, C++ creates shallow copies.  That is to say, the behavior is to call the default copy constructor for the first member (found at the address specified by the data structure) on the second using the first's as a parameter.  Further more, the members of each data structure are always aligned the same (that is to say, for instance, a struct lain out so that it is a float then an int, will reserve the first 4 bytes to the float and the next 4 for the int).

For reference, read this;
http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/912-shallow-vs-deep-copying/

Comment: There is no "default copy constructor". You probably mean the "[implicitely declared copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor#Implicitly-declared_copy_constructor)".

Comment: How is that not a default when the behavior is always the same unless defined otherwise?

Comment: The behavior of the default copy constructor is not to copy byte by byte. It is to copy member by member. For members with non-trivial copy constructors, that means calling those copy constructors, not copying their bytes.

Comment: I'm going to rectify that because you are right; it does call their respective copy constructors.

Comment: The term "shallow copies" is more confusing than helpful. The default copy constructor performs member-wise copies. What the copy of each member does depends on the semantics of the copy construction of the members. In most cases, this is value semantics.

Comment: Shallow copy is the correct terminology.  When you have pointers in a struct, it only causes the copies to have the same address.